# Error when combining string in c-shell

Tags: linux, shell, csh

For generating a file per hour, I want to use a c-shell script.

The datetime was already set in the `.csh` (e.g., 2014-11-30-12 in the code below).

I want to generate a directory named `2014_11_30_12`, but I don't know how to concatenate them.

```
#!/bin/csh -f
set year = "2014"
foreach strtime (113012120412)

set smon = `echo ${strtime}|cut -c1-2`
set sday = `echo ${strtime}|cut -c3-4`

set filename = `${year}+${smon}+${sday}`
mkdir ./filename
```

I'm fresh on c-shell, so I tried

```
set filename = `$year+$smon+$sday$`
```

But it seems to be the wrong solution.

#### Update

Thanks for the guide. The code below works well.

```
set year = "2014"
foreach strtime (113012120412)

set smon = `echo ${strtime}|cut -c1-2`
set sday = `echo ${strtime}|cut -c3-4`

set filename = "${year}_${smon}_${sday}"
mkdir ./${filename}
```

Comment: It seems odd to be using `+` where you want `-` in the output.  You should show the error — but it says something about a command `2014+01+01` or something similar not being found,  Don't use back-ticks; use double quotes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. By `set filename = "${year}_${smon}_${sday}"
mkdir ./${filename}`. The problem fixed

Comment: Also, you set `$mon` but referenced `$smon`; similarly `$day` and `$sday`; you set `$hr` but don't use it.  Your error might be about referencing undefined variables — C shell thinks that's a crime, whereas the Bourne shell family generally just treats a non-existent variable as containing an empty string.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! @Joyhnathn Leffler. By the way, do you know some method when `mkdir dir_name` and the `dir_name` was already exist. How to label the second one with an _marker_(eg. [Duplication]2014_11_30) in csh?

Comment: At least two options.  One is `mkdir -p "$dir_name"` which won't fail if the directory already exists (and will create the path to the directory if there are directories missing: `mkdir -p /tmp/who/dunnit` will create `/tmp/who` and `/tmp/who/dunnit`).  The other is to test whether the directory exists before running `mkdir`.  I'd probably use `mkdir -p` these days, but in the more distant past, would have done things the other way.

Comment: Maybe I explained the question unclearly. For example, I have already had the directory named `2014_11_30` using the script I mentioned. And the hourly time would repeat an _2014_11_30_. Using `mkdir -p`. The original `2014_11_30` would be __covered__. What I want is to test whether there will be overlapping or not. If there will be name overlapping. Label the latter ones an  _prefix _ as `Duplicate2`. I want to keep both directory due to the different data I would save into it.

Comment: Ah, beg your pardon; I misunderstood.  Yes, it can be done, by testing whether the directory exists and adjusting the name you create.  Assuming you want suffixes in order, then I don't know of a better way than trying each suffix in turn. My C shell is rusty enough that I'd have to read the manual to write the necessary code.  If a random suffix suffices, it is (almost certainly) easier.